# tensorflowinferenceinterface in a thread on android

Tags: android, tensorflow

```
inferenceInterface.feed(inputName, floatValues, 1, inputSize, inputSize, 3);
inferenceInterface.run(new String[]{outputName},logStats);
inferenceInterface.fetch(outputName, output);
```

When I ran my Android project, this part was very slow, so I tried to put this in a Thread. But the following error occurred.

`Failed to run TensorFlow inference with inputs:[input, input], outputs:[output]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Endpoint "input:0" fed more than once.`

I should not use tensorflowinferenceinterface in a Thread??
If so, what are ways I can speed it up?

Comment: You can use it in an AsyncTask so that the UI thread is not obstructed.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal Thank you. But it's still slow in inferenceInterface.run(new String[]{outputName}, logStats);. Do you know why?